# I want to reset the radio when the ajax request is successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Radio Button**

```
 - <form id="form-reset">
                                           @csrf
                                           <input type="hidden" id="questionId" value="{{$data->id}}">
                                           <div class="btn btn-group-toggle d-flex flex-column" id="radioDiv"
                                               data-toggle="buttons">
                                               <label class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">
                                                   <input type="radio" name="options" id="option_a1" class="answer-check-box"
                                                        data-value="1"> Yes
                                               </label>
                                               <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                                                   <input type="radio" name="options" id="option_a2" class="answer-check-box"
                                                        data-value="2"> NO
                                               </label>
                                           </div>
                                       </form>
```

**JS code**

```
function clearRads() {
        var radList = document.getElementsByName("options");

        for (var i = 0; i < radList.length; i++) {
            if (radList[i].checked) {
                document.getElementById(radList[i].id).checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Ajax Success Function**

```
success: function(response) {
                        // console.log(response.data);
                        timeReset();
                        let theInput = document.getElementById('questionId');
                        if (response.data && !(response.data.correct_answer == 0)) {
                            clearRads();
                            theInput.value = response.data.id;
                            $('#question').html(response.data.question);
                        } else {
                            $('#quesDiv1').html('<h4 class="text-center">Please Wait</h4>');
                        }

                    }
```

The problem is that when I call this clearRads() this will not reset the value. This function returns the undefined when i console.log this function. thanks in advance. Please guide me i will be thankful.

Comment: Please reformat the code and ensure you explain the problem clearly with proper context.

Comment: Sure I shall reformat the code..
I want to reset the radio button when the user submits the answer. When the next question appears the radio buttons are unchecked. I am using ajax to get the answer of the question. and then I append the next question and the answer fields resets when next question appears.

Comment: *[clearRads()] returns undefined when I console.log this function* - yes, because there's no `return xxx` statement in clearRads()

Comment: yes, this function shows undefined in the console.

Comment: Your function, *as provided*, works fine as demonstrated [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0j1rnoxf/).   If it's not working for you, then there's some other issue you've not included in the question.  Please provide a *complete* sample that demonstrates the issue.  See [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your `clearRads()` function needs a bit of work.

So instead of what you have, I think this should do the trick:

```
function clearRads() {
  var radList = document.getElementsByName("options");
  for (var i = 0; i < radList.length; i++) {
     radList[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

No need for an if check if you're clearing all checks. Also no need for document.get... since you already have those elements in the array.

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: No this does don't clear the radio buttons instead it affects the count down timer speed.

Comment: @AliHamza This code is a simplified version of what you had - it does exactly the same without the need for ids.  There is *no way* it could affect a "count down timer" (not included in the question), unless that timer relies on options, in which case your code would also have the same effect.   Please edit your question to include enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: sure I will try to figure what is wrong in my code